# Appium can not test iOS Application "The URL '/' did not map to a valid resource"

Tags: ios, appium, appium-ios

Hi I am trying to test iOS application using Appium. I am getting following message in browser when I try to open this link http://127.0.0.1:4723/

"The URL '/' did not map to a valid resource"

Further information:
Appium Version 1.5.3

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by opening this URL in a browser? If you want to check, wether the Appium server is up running, add /wd/hub/status to the URL.

Comment: This is the result of http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub/status  {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.5.3","revision":null}},"sessionId":null. iOS Simulator is also not launching  I mean it should launch on server starting.

Comment: Not exactly. It will start a session (and launch an app in simulator or on a device) once you connect using a WebDriver that tells Appium what to do.

Comment: whats your capabilities?

Comment: @OmerMalik Were you able to get any progress?  I am running into the same issue?  When I run my script, I get the 'org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: The URL '/wb/hub/session' did not map to a valid resource'

Comment: @CLDev Steps to solve run appium with the application iOS or Android application, access it using [Intern Runner](https://theintern.github.io/intern/#what-is-intern). Let me know if you need some help :)

Comment: @OmerMalik ..Can you provide a proper Explanation if you are successful with appium in IOS ..

Comment: @RajatBhadauria please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appium acts like a server which hosts your iOS Application. You can write your tests in java or java script for writing tests I used [intern Runner](https://theintern.github.io/intern/#what-is-intern) and configuration of **intern.js** is  below

```
tunnel: 'NullTunnel',
tunnelOptions: {
    hostname: 'localhost',
    port: 4444
},

'capabilities': {
    'selenium-version': '2.48.0',
    'idle-timeout': 60,
    'defaulTimeout':60,
    'chromeOptions': {'args':['allow-ra-in-dev-mode']}
},    

'environments': [
    {browserName: 'chrome'},

],
```

Then you can write your own iOS test in **iOSTest.js**

```
'use strict';

define([
'intern!object',
'intern/chai!assert',
'intern/dojo/node!underscore'],
function(registerSuite,assert,_) {


//set server configurations
registerSuite({
    'name': 'iOS CoApp Testing',

    'setup': function() {
    },

    'teardown': function() {
        // executes after suite ends;
        // can also be called `after` instead of `teardown`
    },

    'beforeEach': function(test) {

    },

    'afterEach': function(test) {
        // executes after each test
    },

    'simple test': function() {

     // it finds text field and insert 124 in it               
          .findByXpath
          ("//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[1]/UIATextField[1]")
          .click()
          .pressKeys('124')
          .end()

    //it finds Button and clicks it              
         .findByXpath
          ("//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[1]/UIAButton[1]")
          .click()
          .end()



        }
    });
});
```